# How to make a for with more than one else if in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, coordinates

I want to associate points in these coordinates and associate them with the correspondent number. However every time I tried to run it I got this: the condition has length > 1

```
for (i in dados) {
    if (dados[dados$latitude>="55.84" & dados$latitude<= "55.95" & dados$longitude>="-3.444" & dados$longitude<="-3.198", ]){
      dados$neighbourhood <- 1
    } else if (dados[dados$latitude>="55.84" & dados$latitude<= "55.95" & dados$longitude>="-3.198" & dados$longitude<="-3.058", ]){
      dados$neighbourhood <- 2
    } else if (dados[dados$latitude>="55.95" & dados$latitude<="56.01" & dados$longitude>="-3.444" & dados$longitude<="-3.198", ]){
      dados$neighbourhood <- 3
    } else if (dados[dados$latitude>="55.95" & dados$latitude<="56.01" & dados$longitude>="-3.189" & dados$longitude<="-3.058", ]){
      dados$neigbourhod <- 4
    }
   }
```

Your help would be much appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: (It looks like your latitude/longitude are text, which could lead to unexpected results for some comparisons if you are looking at a wider range of values; for instance 10.0 will be "less than" 9.9 because 1 is alphabetically lower than 9. Maybe not a problem in your specific data but converting to `as.numeric` would generally be safer.)

Comment: It's more idiomatic in R to make a vectorized formula that will apply to the whole column at once, for instance:`dados$neighborhood = ifelse(condition1, 1, ifelse(condition2, 2, ifelse(condition3, 3, 4)))`. Or I like to avoid a nested ifelse by using `dplyr::case_when`, like `dados %>% mutate(neighborhood = case_when(condition1 ~ 1, condition2 ~ 2, condition3 ~ 3, TRUE ~ 4))`

Comment: 1) You never use the index `i`, it should be `dados$latitude[i]` and `dados$longitude[i]` everywhere; 2) remove `dados[` and `]`, they are doing nothing but causing errors; 3) why compare to characters such as `"55.84"`? I bet you have numbers not character strings. If so, unquote every thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a vectorized way. Use the fact that binary numbers are written with `0/1` times powers of two. And add 1 to have one-based results.

```
i2 <- dados$latitude >= 55.95 & dados$latitude<= 56.01
i1 <- dados$longitude >= -3.198 & dados$longitude <= -3.058
dados$neigbourhod <- 1 + i1 + i2*2
```

Answer (score 0):

Often, you need to execute some statements only when some condition is met. You can use following conditional statements in your code to do this.

if Statement: use it to execute a block of code, if a specified condition is true
else Statement: use it to execute a block of code, if the same condition is false
else if Statement: use it to specify a new condition to test, if the first condition is false
ifelse() Function: use it when to check the condition for every element of a vector